# How to Debug an UPDATE of Universal Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a Universal Windows Phone 8.1 App (.appxupload) and submitted to store. I want to debug an **update** on my device.  When I choose "deploy to device" in Visual Studio 2013, it tells me, that it uninstalls the old app which I installed from marketplace. How can test the update-process? I found 
"Windows Phone Power Tools" on codeplex which only supports silverlight apps (.xap)

Comment: Are you aware that when you update an app from the WP Store, it uninstalls the previous version and then install the new ? Your emulator is doing exactly the same thing. The only thing that differentiate an installation from an update is that the latter keeps your local files and settings.

Comment: I have a problem, that after the update, the secondary livetile does no longer update (same as here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec0e6799-f8bc-4a43-b0af-4b9cc47d29bc/windows-phone-81-the-application-identifier-provided-is-invalid-after-new-app-package?forum=wpdevelop)
So uninstall and new install behaves differently as update. And I wanted to debug it.

Comment: I think quite cloes should be a situation when you install on your phone the old version (debug from VS), then install the new updated version - it will reinstall the app, but preserve local files (similar to update). The best test would be to publish a beta app and test behavior on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT debug store apps without special equipment at all (but Microsoft/OEM engineers are able to do this).
What you can do:
- implement debug output with MessageBox-es instead Debug.WriteLine
- publish beta app
- try it on your handset

You **can't** trace your code, make breakpoints and watch variables. The only tool in your case is a MessageBox (or you may construct other output, like multiline TextBlock just for debug purposes).